# How to make sure the QWidget is out of screen?

Tags: qt

Assume that I have a `QPushButton`, if I pressed the button, then I will show a `QFrame`. When the button is close to the edge of the screen, some part of the `QFrame` can't be seen. How to make sure the `QFrame` is out of window?

Comment: Couldn't you just set the position to -2 times the size of the widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you need following detection method for `QWidget` in general..

```
bool IsOutOfDesktop(QWidget *w)
{
    QDesktopWidget *desktopWidget = QApplication::desktop();
    QRect screenRect = desktopWidget->screenGeometry(&w);
    QPoint topLeft = w.mapToGlobal(w.geometry().topLeft());
    QPoint bottomRight = w.mapToGlobal(w.geometry().bottomRight());

   if(!screenRect.contains(topLeft) || !screenRect.contains(bottomRight))
        return true;

   return false;
}
```